# What is the best way to store a constant values in `Firestore`?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to `non-relational` databases. I am developing a simple react-native app where there is a dropdown list containing the names of the states (eg: Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, California...) I am using [RNPickerSelect](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select) as the dropdown. `RNPickerSelect` requires an array of objects (fields: value and label) which will be rendered as the items of the dropdown. I have hard coded an array of objects containing the names of the states and a unique numerical id which will be passed to the dropdown component as a prop.

```
export const STATES = [{ value: 0, label: 'Alabama' }, { value: 1, label: 'Alaska' }, { value: 2, label: 'Arizona' }, ...]
```

When user selects a value from the dropdown, the value will be stored in the database instead of storing the name of the state. When the app needs to display the selected state in a label it will convert the value stored in the database to it's respective name by using the array shown above.

1. There is no meaning in the data stored in the database as it stores only an id. Is it a bad practice ? Should I store the name of the state instead of storing the id ?
2. Also, if I am going to store the gender (Male / Female) what is the best way to do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no right or wrong way to do this.  Pick whatever works for your app, or whatever you prefer.